# Hiding the loader when updating kartik grid

Tags: php, yii

I have a grid that gets updated every 3 seconds. Everything working fine but the problem is that the loader (showing...loading)  keeps on poping up everytime the grid is updated.

This is what I have tried:

```
  echo DynaGrid::widget([
    'columns' => $columns,
    'showPersonalize' => true,
    'options' => ['id' => 'trackyard'],
    'gridOptions' => [
        'options' => ['id' => 'assignsolicitation-inside'],
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'showPageSummary' => false,
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            'maxButtonCount' => 10,
        ],

        'toolbar' => [
            ['content' => '{dynagrid}'],
            '{export}',
            '{toggleData}'
        ],
        'pjax' => true,
        'pjaxSettings' => [
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'wod'
            ],],
        'bordered' => false,
        'striped' => true,
        'condensed' => true,
        'responsive' => true,
        'responsiveWrap' => false,
        'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow:scroll'],
    ]
]);

?>
```

Then after the grid I have:

```
<?php
  $script = <<< JS
function reloadgrid() {
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
   $.pjax.reload({container:'#trackyard-pjax'});
}, 3000);
setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}, 18000);
};

reloadgrid();
JS;
$this->registerJS($script, \yii\web\VIEW::POS_HEAD);
?>
```

How can i hide the loader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that i needed to set loadingCssClass to false

That is

```
echo DynaGrid::widget([
'columns' => $columns,
'showPersonalize' => true,
'options' => ['id' => 'trackyard'],
'gridOptions' => [
    'options' => ['id' => 'assignsolicitation-inside'],
    ....


    'pjax' => true,
    'pjaxSettings' => [
        'options' => [
            'id' => 'wod'
        ],
      'loadingCssClass'=>false,  //this disables the loading thing

      ],
    .........
   ]
  ]);

 ?>
```

From [Kartik documentation here on pjax settings](http://demos.krajee.com/grid)

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your widget

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'function(id) { $(\'.loader\').hide(); }'
```

Hope that will help you.

Comment: doesnt disable it

Answer (score -1):

for exmp this div si loader

```
<div class="loader"></div>
```

after record update you hide loader div

```
function(data) {
$('.loader').hide();
}
```

Comment: I need to disable the kartik grid loader not a custom created loader